# GitLab Web Hook requires public ip in URL?

Tags: networking, jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

I'm on a internal work network and want to configure GitLab with a web hook to my Jenkins box running locally (run tests on push etc..). The web hook requires a URL: http://{jenkins-url}:port/project/{job-name}. I have tried using the ip address from `ifconfig` and localhost. But neither of them are working. My hunch is that I need a public facing ip and a firewall exception made. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Are you on a self hosted version of gitlab, or on gitlab.com ?

Comment: We are using gitlab.com

If we hosted gitlab on our internal network there wouldn't be an issue with webhooks because everything would stay in network. Correct?

Comment: Yes correct, you have your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want gitlab.com to be able to trigger your jenkins build, then you have to give them a channel to communicate. So you need to have a public accessible URL available for your jenkins webhook, with the port 80 open.

Otherwise you can use gitlab.com's CI features, they are quite powerful. https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/